# ultrasurf is not working in ubuntu

Tags: wine

I would like to use "Ultrasurf" software for ubuntu12.04..I installed wine, and when i'm trying to open ultrasurf with wine,some of versions of ultrasurf's saying some .dll files are missing. I replaced that files correctly in correct place. But still i have same problem. Some of versions are not happennig anything...I searched and did everthing i can.

Is there a way to run ultrasurf in ubuntu however correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to run Ultrasurf in ubuntu. I followed the approach given in [Running Ultrasurf in Ubuntu](http://remotalks.blogspot.com/2013/08/running-ultrasurf-in-ubuntu.html). It is a recent blog post on this topic... This blog also has few other articles related to Ultrasurf.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Install Wine in your System from the website winehq.org . Generally it comes pre installed but in case  you don't have it then do it quickly.

Step 2:
Download the latest Ultrasurf file from the website http://ultrasurf.us/  . Unzip the downloaded file and you will get a .exe file.

Step 3:
Once you are done with step 1 and step 2, you just need to download two more file and you are done.

```
   -> mfc42.dll  

   -> msvcp60.dll
```

Step 4:
Pretty much done. Now you just have to copy both the files at two places. Go to your Home folder and press Ctrl+H. This shows up the hidden files. Locate .wine. Inside the folder follow the path
         drive_c/windows/system
         drive_c/windows/system32
 Paste both the files in both the location. Now you are done.

Step 5:
Now open the .exe file with the help of wine. It takes a while for Ultrasurf to load in Ubuntu, so be patient. Once the software loads change the settings just as you do in Windows.

Thats it !! All set to go ....